# Spark Java : file partition by column name is not working on saving file as xml format

Tags: java, xml, apache-spark

I want to split and save my file as xml on the basis of column name, but below code is not working.

File are getting split automatically.

```
df.write().partitionBy(columnName).format("xml").save(filePath);
```